# How do I add matches as entities and visualize it in spacy?

Tags: spacy

Here I have an animal list stored in a csv file like below:
**["cat","dog","fish","bird"...]** to name a few.
And here is the sentence example: **“I have a cat.”**

Then how can I visualize the match result here in spacy?
A detailed code example would be thankful!

Answer (score 8):

spaCy's built-in [`displacy` visualizer](http://spacy.io/usage/visualizers) lets you pass in one or more `Doc` objects, and will highlight all entities, available as the `doc.ents` property. The `doc.ents` are writable, so you can use the [`PhraseMatcher`](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#adding-phrase-patterns) to find your animals in the text, create a new `Span` object for each match and add it to the existing entities. Here's an example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird']

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # or any other model
patterns = [nlp(animal) for animal in animals]  # process each word to create phrase pattern
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('ANIMAL', None, *patterns)  # add patterns to matcher

doc = nlp("I have a cat")
matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    # create a new Span for each match and use the match_id (ANIMAL) as the label
    span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]  # add span to doc.ents

print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])  # [('cat', 'ANIMAL')]
```

Your `Doc` object now contains an entity span for "cat", so when you run displaCy, the entity will be highlighted. For more details, including how to add custom colours for entities, see [the visualizers documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent).

```
from spacy import displacy
displacy.serve(doc, style='ent')
```

[image: example output]

One important note: Each token can only be part of one entity, so this approach won't work if you have overlapping matches, or if your matches conflict with entities that already exist on the `Doc`. You can prevent this by explicitly filtering out overlapping spans when you iterate over the `matches`. This gives you the `start` and `end` token of the match, so before you add your span to the `doc.ents`, you can check if there's already an entitiy present that overlaps with the start or end position.

For a more elegant solution, you can also wrap your matcher logic in a [custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components). This will trigger it automatically every time you process a text with the `nlp` object.

Comment: Thank you very much! great answer!